# What file or setting controls user backgrounds in unity-greeter?

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, desktop-background, unity-greeter

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial

The unity-greeter background image for my user stopped inheriting my Unity desktop background. Whatever image I use, it is still stuck on Flora...
Selecting guest user changes to the default background, but selecting my username, it uses Flora, whatever different image I use once logged in.

I want to see what went wrong and make it inherit my desktop background image again. How to do it? What files or settings should I check out?

I have already tried changing dconf settings around com.canonical.unity-greeter schema, but had no luck at all...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem an find a way. Look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM
Changing the Wallpaper. I have created the file

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override
```

and compiled it with

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

It worked for me.